# How to group by with a special condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Currently when I issue this SQL, it gets the distinct username.

I have some distinct usernames, which represent groups, e.g. `GRP_BSN`.

I would like to group all the other usernames (which happens to be numeric) into a group e.g. `GRP_OTHERS`

```
select username, count(*)
from host
where seq between 0 and 2000
group by username;

63149   1
63732   1
64110   2
70987   12
76841   4
GRP_BSN 226
GRP_ASN 243
GRP_DSC 93
```

Can I achieve something like this:

```
GRP_OTHERS 20
GRP_BSN 226
GRP_ASN 243
GRP_DSC 93
```

**EDIT: Modified query from answer**

```
select username, count(*)
from host
  where created_dt 
  -- date selection
  between to_date('2012-may-23 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
  and to_date('2012-may-23 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(username, '^\d+$') THEN 'GRP_OTHERS'
                                                 ELSE username
         END;
```

Comment: I was wondering if we had `GROUP BY ( CONCATE( COL1 AND COL2 ) )`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@bfavaretto is nice (+1 to him), but if you don't know about `username` prefix or they are different you can go with something like:

```
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(username, '^\d+$') THEN 'GRP_OTHERS'
                                                 ELSE username
         END
```

Comment: Yes, that's definitely more flexible than mine!

Comment: @zerkms i seem to hit ORA-00920: invalid relational operator ><

Comment: @Chin Boon: the part of query from my answer cannot cause that. You better show your complete query (in your question)

Comment: @zerkms As it turns out, i am using a 9i Oracle. Please let me know if you have a similar work around query.

Answer (score 6):

Not very efficient, but should work:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN username LIKE 'GRP%' THEN username ELSE 'GRP_OTHERS' END AS username, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM host
WHERE seq BETWEEN 0 AND 2000
GROUP BY CASE WHEN username LIKE 'GRP%' THEN username ELSE 'GRP_OTHERS' END;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do it by putting small groups into one bucket, instead of by a particular name pattern, you could use:

```
select (case when cnt > 100 then username else 'OTHER' end), sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select username, count(*) as cnt
      from host
      where seq between 0 and 2000
      group by username
     ) t
group by (case when cnt > 100 then username else 'OTHER' end)
```