# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle9i

This SQL query seems to be hitting ORA 00920.

```
select username, count(*)
from host
where created_dt 
between to_date('2012-may-23 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
and to_date('2012-may-23 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(username, '^\d+$') THEN 'GRP_OTHERS'
                                                 ELSE username
         END;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here. Case in group by???

Comment: Are you tying to put user name meeting reg ex in one group rest on there user name?

Comment: @ejb_guy please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763043/sql-how-to-group-by-with-a-special-condition

Comment: your created_dt is of type date time?

Comment: Basically, it is trying to check if the username is numeric, e.g. 34535, overrideit as GRP_OTHERS and ad this count to GRP_OTHERS.

Comment: the data_type of created_dt is DATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an Oracle DB to play with, but I imagine it could be because you select `username` but don't group by it. You should be able to get around that by using a subquery:

```
select username, count(*)
from (select CASE
             WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(username, '^\d+$') THEN 'GRP_OTHERS'
                                                 ELSE username
         END as username
      from host
      where created_dt 
      between to_date('2012-may-23 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
          and to_date('2012-may-23 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss')
     )
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: Thanks. It still gives me the same error, pin-points to row/col somewhere here "... +$') THEN ..."

Comment: A couple more thoughts, then. I'm not sure if Oracle regexp supports `\d`. You may want to use `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]` instead. What version of Oracle are you using? Is it possible that it doesn't recognize `REGEXP_LIKE` for some reason? Try something like `select 1 from dual where regexp_like('123', '^[0-9]$')` and see if you get an error...

Comment: i'm using 9i, i will check on your recommendation now.

Comment: Ah, it appears `REGEXP_LIKE` was introduced in 10G... [This](http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.jp/2009/06/regexpreplace-regexplike-for-oracle-9i.html) might help you out... Or you can do some [googling](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=REGEXP_LIKE+oracle+9i) to find other workarounds ^_^

Comment: Thanks. I am accepting this as an answer, never expected this to be due to 9i.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite trust what you're posted...

Your query should throw `ORA-00979: Not a GROUP BY expression`. This is because the columns not included in an analytic function, namely `username` are not reflected in your `group by`.

ORA-00920 implies that you are missing one of the following: `=, <>, not in, in, !=, is not null, is null, not like, like` etc. Are you sure you've posted the correct query?

In 11.2, creating something that approximates your table, like so:

```
create table host
(  username varchar2(100)
 , created_dt date );

 insert into host
 select level, sysdate - level
   from dual
connect by level <= 10
        ;

 insert into host
 select chr(ascii(level) + 32), sysdate - level
   from dual
connect by level <= 10
        ;
 commit ;
```

and then running the query posted results in ORA-00979. Changing this to the following work's fine.:

```
select case when regexp_like(username, '^\d+$') then 'GRP_OTHERS'
            else username end as username
     , count(*)
  from host
 where created_dt between
       to_date('2012-may-23 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') and
       to_date('2012-may-23 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 group by case when regexp_like(username, '^\d+$') then 'GRP_OTHERS'
               else username end
       ;
```

This can alternatively be re-written as:

```
select distinct username
     , count(*) over ( partition by case when regexp_like(username, '^\d+$') 
                                               then 'GRP_OTHERS'
                                          else username end )
  from host
 where created_dt between
       to_date('2012-may-23 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss') and
       to_date('2012-may-23 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mon-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

I think this second query is more like what you want. It returns the actual user-name, but groups all those that are just digits together. Just replace the username column returned by the case if you want to see `GRP_OTHERS` instead.

It's slightly better [not to use the `mon` format model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178292/comparing-dates-in-oracle-sql/10178346#10178346) in Oracle as it's not, necessarily, consistent across languages. Use `mm` instead.

---

As you're using 9i you can use translate instead. Replace the regexes with:

```
trim(translate(username,'0123456789',' ')) is null
```

This replaces numbers with nothing and then checks to see if there's anything left...

Comment: thank you, it seems that i am using Oracle 9i, and it does not fully support regexp_like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763043/sql-how-to-group-by-with-a-special-condition would you have an alternative to this, knowing that regexp_like doesn't work in 9i